# using svn://localhost/repos works fine. using svn+ssh://localhost/repos: got No repository found

Tags: svn, ssh, repository

i am setting up a svn repository.
   everything got ready.
   when i typed  svn list svn://localhost/repos/, it showed the repository correctly.
   when i typed  svn list svn+ssh://localhost/repos, it said svn: No repository found in 'svn+ssh://localhost/repos/ktbdbms'

```
user account and password all correct.
```

do i miss anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up a bit more about using svn:// vs svn+ssh://, [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) in SVN book. Connecting to localhost, on your machine, with svnserve is relatively easy, setting up svn+ssh:// is a bit more complicated and requires careful planning. Read the book and set it up, if you want to.

Comment: hi, the problem is on the URL. when you svn:  you set the root path of repository when you start svnserve as a deamon $ svnserve --daemon --root   /svn, in which /svn is your root of the repository.

Comment: when you use svn+ssh, the URL should be the absolute path , which is svn+ssh://localhost/svn/repos.    that's the trick. basically, it has nothing to do with ssh settings

Comment: My bad :) I had mistakenly assumed that you were setting this up on a remote server and thus needing to use svn+ssh:// for ensuring adequate security.

Comment: well, it's a redhat linux server. i will use eclipse ide to connect to this server to check in/out code using svn+ssn.  everything is default. i don't do any changes. not a system admin guru. thanks for you book

Answer (score 0):

svn+ssh uses svnserve.  if you do a `pgrep` for `svnserve` it is likely run with `-r /path/to/repos` and the repository on the filesystem would be `/path/to/repos/ktbdbms`

a common solution is to move `svnserve` to `svnserve.bin` and create a bash script named svnserve which runs:

```
#!/bin/bash
svnserve -r /path/to/repos $*
```